# IF Statement in MYSQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add condition if user input language matches url language

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, IF(url_lang = 'en', weight = (weight+1.1)<10, weight = (weight-1.1)<10) as user_language_weight
                      FROM links                
                      WHERE (status='active'
                            AND type='url' 
                            AND MATCH(title,description,keywords) AGAINST('($op_word_1*) | ($op_word_2*) | ($op_word_3*) | ($op_word_4*) | ($op_word_5*) | ($acc_op_word_1) | ($acc_op_word_2) | ($acc_op_word_3) | ($acc_op_word_4) | ($acc_op_word_5)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                      GROUP BY host
                      ORDER BY weight DESC
```

According to the above, if statement is not working, I'm missing some logic here. Anyone care to correct or explain ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with the `if` expression. Could you give some sample data and expected output?

Comment: There is a lot wrong in this query. You are grouping and should not select `*`

Comment: @Nick, I want to favour some url's, give them a higher weight if url language equals user input language, in this example English.

Comment: @juergen I want to list only higher url by weight from each host

Comment: But why the `<` in the `(weight+1.1)<10` expression?

Comment: @Nick To exclude url's with weight higher than 10. The whole query without the IF statement works perfectly, it seems that IF statement doesn't change anything.

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for comments.
Got the IF statement working, ex:

```
SELECT *, IF(url_lang = 'en', weight +1.1, weight -1.1) AS weight 
                  FROM links                
                  WHERE (status='active'
                        AND type='url' 
                        AND MATCH(title,description,keywords) AGAINST('($op_word_1*) | ($op_word_2*) | ($op_word_3*) | ($op_word_4*) | ($op_word_5*) | ($acc_op_word_1) | ($acc_op_word_2) | ($acc_op_word_3) | ($acc_op_word_4) | ($acc_op_word_5)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                  GROUP BY host
                  ORDER BY weight DESC
```